# Flutter: is there any navigation and routing cheat sheet?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

as I'm coding some app I was wondering if there's any cheat sheet explaining `navigation` and `routing` options I have and when should I use the specific one (for which usecase its the best solution)?

For example I'm creating a `form`, when I press the `button` I need to load a `list` of `items` (`Listview`) from which I will chose one item and go back to the `form`. This list should cover all screen (something like full screen modal I guess)

Im not sure what should I use, whether `MaterialPageRoute`, `ModalRoute` or maybe somethig different like dialog?

Is there any good source to learn besides of reading documentation?

Comment: Have tried googling?

Comment: yes, I have tried

Comment: There are tons of resources on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31) for push and pop concepts. An [example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) related to that.

[This](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes) example is for routing.

See [this](https://blog.usejournal.com/flutter-advance-routing-and-navigator-df0f86f0974f) and [this](https://blog.usejournal.com/flutter-advance-routing-and-navigator-971c1e97d3d2) for complete understanding of Routing and Navigation

Comment: I've seen this before, looking more for something like short comparison between routing methods, but thanks for ansert anyway